# Can not figure how to call a method with Jbutton

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton

i have been running to into trouble trying to write if else statements for this JButton. I am trying to get this Jbutton to call a calculation method
i am using Eclipse and this is Java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;

public class DirectorySize {

protected static final JTextComponent filelist = null;
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField sizeOutput;
protected File file;
protected Object path;
protected long size;
protected Object getContenPane;
protected Object directory;
private int totalFolder;
private int totalFile;



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DirectorySize window = new DirectorySize();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 */
public DirectorySize() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 553, 144);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(10, 11, 402, 35);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    //JFileChooser to open directory
    JButton directoryButton = new JButton("Directory");
    directoryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileHidingEnabled(true);
            chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode    
                           (JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
            int state = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if (state == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )

    textField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

        }
    });
    directoryButton.setBounds(422, 17, 105, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(directoryButton);

    //Jbutton to calculate directory size when pressed
    JButton sizeReader = new JButton("Calculate Size");
    sizeReader.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String sizeReader = sizeOutput.getText();
            String fs = "foldersize";
                if(fs == sizeReader){

                }else{


            //sizeOutput.setText(sizeOutput.getText() + totalFolder);
                }
        }
    });
    sizeReader.setBounds(10, 57, 131, 38);
    frame.getContentPane().add(sizeReader);

    sizeOutput = new JTextField();
    sizeOutput.setEditable(false);
    sizeOutput.setBounds(151, 57, 261, 38);
    frame.getContentPane().add(sizeOutput);
    sizeOutput.setColumns(10);

    // exit button for frame
    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Exit");
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private Object exitButton;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            System.exit(0);

            this.add(exitButton);
        }

        private void add(Object exitButton2) {

        }
    });
    btnNewButton_2.setBounds(422, 65, 105, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

}

  //Calculation method for the directories
  public long getFileSize(File folder) { 
    totalFolder++;  
    System.out.println("Folder: " + folder.getName()); 
    long foldersize = 0; 

    File[] filelist = folder.listFiles(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) { 
        if (filelist[i].isDirectory()) { 
            foldersize += getFileSize(filelist[i]); 
        } else { 
            totalFile++; 
            foldersize += filelist[i].length(); 
        } 
    } 
    return foldersize; 
} 
public int getTotalFolder() { 
    return totalFolder; 
} 
public int getTotalFile() { 
    return totalFile; 
} 
   }
```

can somebody please help me and tell me what i am doing wrong or what do i need to do
Thanks for you help

Comment: SizeOutput is also a button ???

Comment: i have tried if/else statements and try catch but i cant seem to get it right

Comment: Comparison of Strings `a` and `b` in Java is `a.equals(b)`. Expression `a == b` is only true if `a` and `b` refer to exactly the same object. So I think your if statement is not doing what you want.

Comment: are you going to consider "FolderSize" being lowercase or uppercase?

Comment: im trying to get the Jbutton to call the calculation method. but i dont know what i am doing wrong and when i compile it i get a 0 instead of the size of a Directory folder

Comment: @tunmisefasipe your right that was a typo i meant to have it lowercase

Comment: to me, your code seems not to be complete. I can't see where you called your function or how you passed your folder variable

Comment: I did not show my whole code because i was only having problems getting the right if/else statement for my Jbutton to call the calculation method. if you want i can post the whole code?

Comment: in Java, variable should have the first word as lowercase. Your SizeReader, SizeOutput variable was not and makes it look like a class. Stick to that recommended coding pattern

Comment: I have uploaded the whole code so you can see what i am trying to work on here. maybe you can run it?

Comment: Please add to the question what you exactly want to do? More precisely What part of the code you want help for? What you expect and what you currently get. Also report any compile-time/run-time exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
String SizeReader = SizeOutput.getText().toLowerCase();
if(fs.toLowerCase().equals(SizeReader))
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: *"i get an Exception"*  I am guessing you got some exception output.  So that we don't have to make further guesses, edit it into your question.

Comment: What? my code is fine it does not have any compiling error, its just when i add the if/else statement that @tunmise fasipe gave me then i would get an exception error.